# I seem to be missing something... PHP Variable of Variable Foreach

Tags: php, variables, dynamic

Currently I have a few loops that produce options for different sections in wordpress.

Creates a section in the theme options for each published page. 
The options include an area to set a background for each section.

- Create each option section? - Check
- Create an ID for each section based on page title? - Check
- Get the background to set based on what is stored on the database, matching the generated option id? -- This is where I am stuck...see the code below, maybe I am missing something.

Here is the code that generates the option section in the theme options panel. 
Currently I am only focused  the one labeled background_image.

```
global $post;
$args = array(
              'sort_order' => 'ASC',
              'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
              'post_type' => 'page',
              'post_status' => 'publish'
              ); 
$pages = get_pages($args); 
foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    $page_title = $page->post_title;
    $trim_it_up = preg_replace('/[^\w]+/', '_', $page_title); //remove any punctuation, spaces, etc. from the title. 
    $time_it_up = strtolower($trim_it_up);
    $options[] = array(
                       'name' => __(  $page_title . ' Page', 'endlyss'),
                       'class' => 'inner_section_header');
    $options[] = array(
                       'name' => __($page_title . ' Background Color One (Gradient)' , 'endlyss'),
                       'id' => $page_title . '_bg_color_one',
                       'std' => '$background_defaults',
                       'type' => 'color');

    $options[] = array(
                       'name' => __($page_title . ' Background Color Two (Gradient)' , 'endlyss'),
                       'id' => $page_title . '_bg_color_two',
                       'std' => '$background_defaults',
                       'type' => 'color');

    $options[] = array(
                       'name' => __('Background Image', 'endlyss'),
                       'id' => $trim_it_up . '_background_image',
                       'std' => '',
                       'type' => 'upload');
}
```

Here is the php in the dynamic CSS file that should pull each variable from the generated options:

```
global $post;
$args = array(
              'sort_order' => 'ASC',
              'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
              'post_type' => 'page',
              'post_status' => 'publish'
              ); 
$pages = get_pages($args); 
foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    $page_title = $page->post_title;
    $trim_it_up = preg_replace('/[^\w]+/', '_', $page_title); //remove any punctuation, spaces, etc. from the title. 
    $trim_it_up = strtolower($trim_it_up);
    ${'{$trim_it_up}_section_background_image'} = of_get_option( $trim_it_up .'_background_image');
};
```

And then finally the php that SHOULD be generating the CSS for each section's background.

```
$args = array(
              'sort_order' => 'ASC',
              'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
              'post_type' => 'page',
              'post_status' => 'publish'
              ); 
unset($trim_it_up);
$pages = get_pages($args);  //Store a list of pages according to the above arguments
foreach ( $pages as $page ) { //begin a loop to set the background for the element based on it's dynamic ID
    $page_title = $page->post_title; //Get the Page title to use later
    $trim_it_up = preg_replace('/[^\w]+/', '_', $page_title); //remove any punctuation, spaces, etc. from the title. 
    $trim_it_up = strtolower($trim_it_up);
    echo "#" . $trim_it_up . "{
    background-image: url(" . ${'{$trim_it_up}_section_background_image'} . ");
    }
    ";
}
```

This is the output that I am getting:

```css
#home{
    background-image: url();
}
#services{
    background-image: url();
}
#portfolio{
    background-image: url();
}
#contact{
    background-image: url();
}
```

What I am going for is: Each of those background image urls should be filled with the url stored from the theme options. 
There are no error messages, just somewhere, something does not add up...and I cannot figure out where.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

---

Solution found: 
Combined the second and third sets of code into one, and came up with the following:

```
$args = array(
    'sort_order' => 'ASC',
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
    ); 
$pages = get_pages($args); 
foreach ( $pages as $page ) { 
    $page_title = $page->post_title;
    $trim_it_up = preg_replace('/[^\w]+/', '_', $page_title);
    $trim_it_up = strtolower($trim_it_up);
    $background_image_url = of_get_option($trim_it_up . '_background_image');
    echo "#" . $trim_it_up . "{
        background-image: url(" . $background_image_url . ");
    }";
}
```

Basically Brought the of_get_option into the for_each loop, rather than create it outside of the loop. That way, I didnt have a different variable for each one, just one that would be re-used each time around.

Comment: Why not use associative arrays instead of variable variables?

Comment: Please indent your code so it's readable.

Comment: Apologies. Indented. Checking out your examples below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code that uses the variable variables is in a different function than the code that assigns them, you need to make the variables global.

Another problem is that you had the wrong type of quotes around your variable variables. You used single quotes, but variables are only interpolated inside double quotes.

```
foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    $page_title = $page->post_title;
    $trim_it_up = preg_replace('/[^\w]+/', '_', $page_title); //remove any punctuation, spaces, etc. from the title. 
    $trim_it_up = strtolower($trim_it_up);
    global ${"{$trim_it_up}_section_background_image"};
    ${"{$trim_it_up}_section_background_image"} = of_get_option( $trim_it_up .'_background_image');
};
```

and the second must do:

```
foreach ( $pages as $page ) { //begin a loop to set the background for the element based on it's dynamic ID
    $page_title = $page->post_title; //Get the Page title to use later
    $trim_it_up = preg_replace('/[^\w]+/', '_', $page_title); //remove any punctuation, spaces, etc. from the title. 
    $trim_it_up = strtolower($trim_it_up);
    global ${"{$trim_it_up}_section_background_image"};
    echo "#" . $trim_it_up . "{
    background-image: url(" . ${"{$trim_it_up}_section_background_image"} . ");
    }
    ";
}
```

But instead of using variable variables, you could just use a single associative array. Then you could just declare this one variable global at the top of each function, or return it from one function and pass it as an argument to the other.

First function:

```
global $section_background_image;
$section_background_image = array();
foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    $page_title = $page->post_title;
    $trim_it_up = preg_replace('/[^\w]+/', '_', $page_title); //remove any punctuation, spaces, etc. from the title. 
    $trim_it_up = strtolower($trim_it_up);
    $section_background_image[$trim_it_up] = of_get_option( $trim_it_up .'_background_image');
};
```

Second function:

```
global $section_background_image;
foreach ( $pages as $page ) { //begin a loop to set the background for the element based on it's dynamic ID
    $page_title = $page->post_title; //Get the Page title to use later
    $trim_it_up = preg_replace('/[^\w]+/', '_', $page_title); //remove any punctuation, spaces, etc. from the title. 
    $trim_it_up = strtolower($trim_it_up);
    global ${"{$trim_it_up}_section_background_image"};
    echo "#" . $trim_it_up . "{
    background-image: url(" . $section_background_image[$trim_it_up] . ");
    }
    ";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, globalizing the variables did not work, either 
However, I went away for a little while and came back with an idea. 
I pulled the of_get_option into the last set of code (the second one in your above)...my solution is posted above.

HOWEVER(again..haha) I am curious as to what you suggest, especially if it is a more efficient means to my method. 

How would I go about creating the single associative array? (I apologize to ask, but I learn by example and backwards engineering :\ )

Comment: I found another problem in your code, regarding quotes. I updated my answer to show the fix for that. I also added a version showing how to use the associative array.

Comment: That worked perfectly.
Thank you very much. Also, thank you for introducing me to associative arrays. I just started this kinda stuff a couple days ago, so definitely appreciating efficiency pointers and help with any problems that I come across.